# Converting command line Options to one single variable in weblogic wlst

Tags: python, shell, wlst

"I am trying to pass a bunch of jvm arguments from my shell script to a wlst script as command line arguments. The wlst script seems to be picking only the first value of the jvm argumentsand ignore the rest after "space". I tried inserting the whole string in quotes as well. But it didn't work. Is there any I can pass all these as one variable into wlst?

```
JVMARGUMENTS="-Xms250 -Xmx500 -DWeb"

./weblogic.py $value1 $value2 $jvmarguments

where weblogic.py contains something like below:
variable1=sys.argv[1]
variable2=sys.argv[2]
variable3=sys.argv[3] ( this is not picking the whole jvm args but only -Xms250)
```

Please advise"

Comment: This also has nothing to do with Python and everything with the shell variable interpolation rules. It also depends on the shell used!

Answer (score 3):

You should wrap your arguments in **double quotes**.

```
./weblogic.py "$value1" "$value2" "$JVMARGUMENTS"
```